# Not routing to other pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I'm creating a wordpress site with astra sites and when I click on about or other links it give me the following error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at <my ip> Port 80
```

I have also created a .htaccess file in the directory where my index.php file is and gave permissions too.But it didn't work.Please help this is my first wordpress site.
Following is my curren .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). Please review their help section first before posting to see how to write your question so that it meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

One of the below points would solved your issue:

1. Can you please try to follow below mentioned stepes:

- Open WordPress login page
- logged in with admin credentials
- Go to Settings menu from left sidebar in admin panel
- Click on Permalinks submenu item
- save the permalinks

2. If you are going to setup this project in local machine, then please add project folder name in below lines:

From:
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

To:
RewriteRule ^foldername\index.php$ - [L]

From:
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

To:
RewriteRule . /foldername/index.php [L]

3. You might need to remove restriction from the server's conf file if you are working on Live server

Comment: @Sahan Thilakarathna, Please let me know if you still have any issue after above steps.